# Sub Menu Rollover Pop up Not Showing

Tags: html, css

hopefully this will be an easy answer for some of you CSS veterans out there.

I'm developing a site for a client. For readability, I'll just give you a link to the website and the css page in question.
[HTML](http://whitelambfinlay.com/wlfbackend/index.html)
[CSS](http://whitelambfinlay.com/wlfbackend/stylesheet.css)

I'm trying to make a sub menu pop up to the right of the main menu when you scroll over "Star Quartz Grout." My current CSS obviously isn't correct though, and I could use some guidance.

```
ul#subNav {display: none; width: 134px; }
li:hover ul#subNav, li.over ul#subNav {display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 134px; }
```

My guess is that it's working but it's hidden behind the rest of the page. I could be wrong though. It's kind of hard to confirm, even with Chrome's "Inspect Element" (very nice thing btw). It's probably some dumb mistake. Anyway, thanks in advance. I'm a bit of a CSS novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
ul#subNav ul
{
display: none;
}

ul#subNav li:hover ul
{
display:block;
}
```

But be careful because your "li" zone is smaller than the link itself.

I did it this way on this website : [Spirit Of Polo](http://spiritofpolo.com/en/top_products) (hover the shopping cart).
Be careful, this kind of effect (hover) will not be visible on touch-screen devices (because hover is impossible if you think about it)

Comment: Hm, didn't work. Some sort of positioning has to be required right?

Psuedo code:
Rollover state = false: hide
Rollover state = true: unhide and display the right of the main menu by the amount of the sub menu's button width.

I've re-uploaded the HTMl and CSS so the links above reflect the changes. The only difference that made is that the "Star Quartz Grout" button now has it's rollover state working. Not sure how that happened, but I would have had to fix it anyway, lol.

Comment: Looks like you succeeded no ? But it only works in the main page